# PowerMock with final class System and static Method currentTimeMillis

Tags: java, methods, static, final, powermock

I do not understand why PowerMock do it this way.

Test-Class

```
public class Testimpl {
    public long test() {
        long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("2: " + a);
        return a;
    }
}
```

jUnit-Class

```
import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(System.class)
public class TestimplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    Testimpl testimpl;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        initMocks(testimpl);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        PowerMockito.when(System.currentTimeMillis()).thenReturn(12345l);
        System.out.println("1: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        long a = testimpl.test();
        System.out.println("3: " + a);
    }

}
```

Output:

> 1: 12345
>
> 2: 1422547577101
>
> 3: 1422547577101

Why this works PowerMock/Mockito correctly in the jUnit TestimplTest class and not in the tested Testimpl class?

I use jUnit 4.11 and Mockito 1.9.5 with PowerMock 1.6.1.

Thank you for your Help.

Answer (score 7):

The annotation `@PrepareForTest` must have your tested class to correctly mock the `System.currentTimeMillis()` method. Source and more information on that: [PowerMock wiki](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockSystem)

With the correct class in `@PrepareForTest` annotation: `@PrepareForTest(Testimpl.class)`, I have the expected output:

> 1: 12345
>   2: 12345
>   3: 12345

Comment: Awesome..Had same issue.Worked for me.

Comment: @TheLion, did you manage to mock `System.currentTimeMillis`? I read on https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/PowerMock-Configuration that by default PowerMock loaded all classes with its MockClassLoader. The classloader loads and modified all classes except system classes. So it looks like we can't mock Java static methods and have to write wrappers. I wrote one, and it works: https://gist.github.com/MaksimDmitriev/202142b6345ae86a3fda7577390fb1bf. And this https://gist.github.com/MaksimDmitriev/1ceea5c08abb5fa9dc485fce7f71f630 doesn't

Answer (score 0):

The other answer did not work for me, but here's a good example based on [Maksim Dmitriev's gist](https://gist.github.com/MaksimDmitriev/202142b6345ae86a3fda7577390fb1bf).

The trick is to introduce a wrapper class like `SystemUtils.java` that provides a public static accessor to the `System` method. Then run `spy` on it and mock the method.

Here is the sample:

`FileUtils.java`:

```
package sample.com.sample_app;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

public class FileUtils {
    @NonNull
    public static String generateName() {
        return Long.toString(SystemUtils.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

`FileUtilsTest.java`:

```
package sample.com.sample_app;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SystemUtils.class})
public class FileUtilsTest {

    @Test
    public void generateName() {
        PowerMockito.spy(SystemUtils.class);
        PowerMockito.when(SystemUtils.currentTimeMillis()).thenReturn(100L);

        String name = FileUtils.generateName();
        assertEquals("100", name);
    }
}
```

`SystemUtils.java`:

```
package sample.com.sample_app;

public class SystemUtils {

    private SystemUtils() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    public static long currentTimeMillis() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```